# Generate blocks of 128MB in Nifi

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi, cloudera

What I'm trying to do is to deposit into HDFS blocks of size of 128MB I've been trying several processors but can't get the good one or I haven't identify the correct property:

This is how prety much the flow looks like:

[image]

- Right now I'm using PutParquet but this processor doesn't have a property to do that
- The previous processor is a MergeContent and this is the configuration
  [image]
- and on the SplitAvro I have next configuration

[image]

Hope someone can help I'm really stuck trying to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the SplitAvro or ConvertAvroToJSON, if you use MergeRecord instead you can supply an AvroReader and JsonRecordSetWriter and it will do the conversion for you. If you know the approximate number of records that will fit in an HDFS block, you can set that as the Maximum Number of Entries and also the Max Group Size. Keep in mind those are soft limits though, so you might want to set it to something safer like 100MB.

When you tried with your flow from the description, what did you observe? Were the files still too big, or did it not seem to obey the min/max limits, etc.?

Comment: What I did at the end is check how many records are translate into files below 128MB, I configure my SplitAvro processor for specify size.